# jQuery: perform ajax request after response from another function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I have this form

```
<form action="ajax/add-category" method="post" class="default-form" id="preventForm">
    <h2 class="form-title">Nuova categoria</h2>
    <div class="cf form-type cols-full">
        <div class="form-object">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="text" class="req" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome categoria">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="form-btn btn-medium btn-green check-inputs" id="submitCategory">Aggiungi categoria</button>
    <button type="button" class="cancel-overlay">Annulla</button>
</form>
```

and I have two separate functions.

1. The first function is executed if the `button` has a class `check-inputs` and it returns a response(`true`/`false`) if the inputs with the class `req` are all filled.
2. The second function performs an AJAX to insert the data in the database.

I want the second function to only execute if the first returns `true`, so if all the required inputs are filled.

This is the AJAX function

```
/* submit the form via ajax */
$(document).on('click', '#submitCategory', function(){

    var $self   = $(this),
        $form   = $self.closest('form'),
        url     = $form.prop('action'),
        method  = $form.prop('method'),
        data    = $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        success: function(rsp) {
            console.log(rsp);
        }
    });

});
```

Is this possible or do I have to merge the two functions ?

I would like to keep them separate so I can use the first function that check the inputs for other AJAX requests as well.

Thank you.

EDIT

**I should have mentioned that the two functions are in two separate files, the response is not global.**

Comment: Use an `if` block to test the condition of the first function for the clicked button. How can you write code to make an AJAX request, but not know how to write an `if` statement?

Comment: can you please show us the other function so we can provide a usable answer?

Comment: Where is the validation function? How does it need to be called? How does it tie in with your other code? In what way is the obvious `if (!validateFunction()) return;` insufficient?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the two functions are in two separate files, the response is not global.

Comment: if they're in another file then you must use cookies to get the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way using global `window` scope:

JS1:

```
window.yourCheckFunction = function() {
    ...
    // return true or false
}
```

JS2:

```
/* submit the form via ajax */
$(document).on('click', '#submitCategory', function(){

    var $self   = $(this),
        $form   = $self.closest('form'),
        url     = $form.prop('action'),
        method  = $form.prop('method'),
        data    = $form.serialize();

    if (yourCheckFunction()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function(rsp) {
                console.log(rsp);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

But better to organize the code using modules. You'll have a few `JS` files that create/extend one module, with module's scope accessible from any module's function. Bonus - you'll be able to use such technique as `RequireJS` to load `JS` files on demand.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but how can I do the same thing when the two functions are in two separate files ? Right now I am doing it how you posted, but is there any way to separate them ?

Comment: Attach your check function to the scope seen by your click handler. For example, in separate file use `window.yourCheckFunction = function() { ... }`. Also read about JavaScript code organization using modules approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, working fine now. Any downsides on attaching the function to the window object ? It seems pretty clean this way.

Comment: OK if your project is not large. Otherwise you'll have a lot of stuff in the global scope, hard to manage, messy etc.